# Gensim-python: Is there a simple way to get the number of times a given token arise in all documents?

Tags: nlp, gensim

My gensim model is like this:

```
class MyCorpus(object):
    parametersList = []
    def __init__(self,dictionary):
       self.dictionary=dictionary
    def __iter__(self):
        #for line in open('mycorpus.txt'):
        for line in texts:
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield self.dictionary.doc2bow(line[0].lower().split())




if __name__=="__main__":
    texts=[['human human interface computer'],
             ['survey user user computer system system system response time'],
             ['eps user interface system'],
             ['system human system eps'],
             ['user response time'],
             ['trees'],
             ['graph trees'],
             ['graph minors trees'],
             ['graph minors minors survey survey survey']]


    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line[0].lower().split() for line in texts)

    corpus= MyCorpus(dictionary)
```

The frequency of each token in each document is automatically evaluated.

I also can define the tf-idf model and access the tf-idf statistic for each token in each document.

```
model = TfidfModel(corpus)
```

**However, I have no clue how to count (memory-friendly) the number of documents that a given word arise. How can I do that?** [Sure... I can use the values of tf-idf and document frequency to evaluate it... However, I would like to evaluate it directly from some counting process]

For instance, for the first document, I would like to get somenthing like

```
[('human',2), ('interface',2), ('computer',2)]
```

since each token above arises twice in each document.

For the second.

```
[('survey',2), ('user',3), ('computer',2),('system',3), ('response',2),('time',2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
from collections import Counter

documents = [...]
count_dict = [word_count(document) for filename in documents]

total = sum(count_dict, Counter())
```

I assumed that all your string are different documents/files. You can make related changes. Also, made change to the code.

Comment: thank you. But, sorry, I did not understand. What is "documents"? Documents=texts? In count_dict = [word_count(document) for filename in documents], what is "document", word_count (the list compreension is done for filename). Finaly, what is counters and Counter? For me, it seems that you are counting all the time a given word arise in all documents, but maybe I am wrong (?). I am asking for something different the number of documents a word arises.

Comment: Made changes to the answer. The counters thing was a spelling mistake. Corrected code